# Float to string without scientific notation?

Tags: erlang, elixir

Is there a good way to convert floats to strings in Erlang/Elixir, without scientific notation, and without specifying how many decimal digits I want?

Neither of these do what I need.

`:erlang.float_to_binary(decimals: 10)`: gives trailing zero decimals
`float_to_binary(100000000000.0, [short]).`: prints scientific notation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can provide the [`compact`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#float_to_list-2) option to trim trailing zeros:

```elixir
iex> :erlang.float_to_binary(100000000000.0, [:compact, decimals: 20])
"100000000000.0"
```

Note however that floats cannot be accurately represented as decimals, so you may end up with unexpected results. For example:

```elixir
iex> :erlang.float_to_binary(0.1 + 0.2, [:compact, decimals: 10])
"0.3"
iex> :erlang.float_to_binary(0.1 + 0.2, [:compact, decimals: 20])
"0.30000000000000004441"
```